# i try to write a text with first letter bigger than other with flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface

i try to write a text with first letter bigger than other with flutter
i am working with fkutter and i don't know how can i make the first letter at this text appear to be bigger than other text like this image
note i receive  the text from the API

```
            Text(
"rsenal will have to grind it out against Aston Villa if they are to register,"
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image: flutter UI]

Comment: You can use `RichText` widget, check following link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Comment: Thsnks i will try it❤️

Answer (score 2):

Try the RichText widget, here is an example:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: '...',
    style: ...,
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'A', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
      TextSpan(text: '....', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: i will get the text from Api hoe can I detect the first letter

Comment: @alsayedabdelbaqey 
example="rsenal will have to grind it out against Aston Villa if they are to register,"
Text(example[0])
Text(example.replace(example[0]))